# Network or timeout limitations while inserting a list into Redis

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, elastic-cache

I have a huge list that I'm inserting into Redis, but it fails.

```
one_million = [18081681, 18081686, ....] // list of 1 million integers, 8-9 digits long
ten_million =  [18081681, 18081686, ....] // list of 10 million integers, 8-9 digits long
```

While inserting the `one_million` list works

```
redis.lpush('random', *one_million) // works
```

inserting the `ten_million` list doesn't

```
redis.lpush('random', *ten_million)
```

The above line gives this error

```
ConnectionError: Error 104 while writing to socket. Connection reset by peer.
```

But I can still insert 10 million items in chunks

```
for _ in range(10):
    redis.lpush('random', *one_million)
```

This works and Redis now has 10 million integers, taking a total of 50 MB

```
<elasticcache>:6379> memory usage random
(integer) 50048515
<elasticcache>:6379> llen random
(integer) 10000000
```

I'm using AWS ElasticCache, engine version 5.0.6. Weirdly enough, if I do this same thing - inserting 10 million in a single go - for the Redis setup I have on my local MacOS, it works. Apparently, there's something different between the ElasticCache configuration and my local Redis setup default configuration, something related to network limitations or timeouts maybe, but I can't figure out what.

I know about the 512 MB limitation of bulk strings in Redis, controlled by this paramemter - `proto-max-bulk-len` and also about `list-max-listpack-size`, which is about size limitations of each individual list element. But they don't seem to indicate anything for my use case.

Would greatly appreciate help in understanding this.